# Inherited DataContext - bindings not working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

Following situation: I got a base class which provides a little framework for making modal dialogs with an adorner.

The base class has a property of type DataTemplate which contains the actual input scheme (all kinds of input are possible) as well as an object property which contains the mapping model (a model class to which the template binds it's input values).

Because I want to reuse the adorner, I made it have a *ContentControl* which anon has a ContentTemplate with the actual dialog design. The dialog's design contains a ContentControl whose Template is bound to the property in the adorner class. The DataContext of the adorner's ContentControl is set to itself, of course.

Now the embedded ContentControl (in the design) generates the DataTemplate and displays (in the current case) a TextBox. This TextBox now should be bound to the model. Therefore I reused the DataContext of the adorner design template for the actual input template. Here's how I've done it:

**The adorner's ControlTemplate**

```
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="{DynamicResource InputAdornerHeaderBackground}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" CornerRadius="0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Header}"
                           FontSize="{DynamicResource InputAdornerHeaderFontSize}" Foreground="{DynamicResource InputAdornerHeaderForeground}"
                           FontWeight="{DynamicResource InputAdornerHeaderFontWeight}" Margin="8" />
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource InputAdornerBorderBrush}" CornerRadius="0">
            <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{Binding InputControlTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ContentTemplate>
```

**The actual input template (DataTemplate)**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TextInputTemplate">
    <Grid Background="Black" DataContext="{Binding DataContext.InputMapping, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=OneWayToSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0"
                 adorners:InputAdorner.FocusElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Model class**

```
public sealed class TextInputModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Adorner properties**

```
    public DataTemplate InputControlTemplate
    {
        get { return _inputControlTemplate; }
        private set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _inputControlTemplate)) return;
            _inputControlTemplate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public object InputMapping
    {
        get { return _inputMapping; }
        private set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _inputMapping)) return;
            _inputMapping = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

FYI: The model is being dynamically instantiated when the Adorner is being created. It does not get set twice. This must be some kind of binding issue.

The template shows correctly. I see and can input stuff into the textbox, but once I fetch the model all properties are default (""). It did work one or two times but somehow design changes have obviously made it disfunctional.

I don't get what is interfering here as from my point of view all should be set up correctly. I checked the context of the DataTemplate: It is the actual model class. Yet the textbox inputs do not update the property.

**EDIT**:
For some reason it seems that the attatched property is causing this issue. But why is it interfering? It does not override the DataContext, does it?

Comment: And as always it fails at the most simple: UpdateSourceTrigger. Of course this one is set to "FocusLost" by default and since the TextBox doesn't lose focus, it never updates. Difficult to find out when it randomly sets either nothing or ("").